# Java - Calculate area, if area is > 1000 and shape = green, print list of shapes

Tags: java, parsing, math

My program reads a list of shapes, if the area is > 1000 and the colour string matches green, print the shapes.

Sample data below :

Rectangle , width, height,colour -

Circle, radius,colour.

rectangle 68.01 77.63 orange

Main class - rudimentary attempt.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;


public class Main {
    private static String SHAPE_DATA = "shapes.txt";

    public static boolean main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        List<Shape> shapes = ShapeParser.parseFile(SHAPE_DATA);
        for(int = 0 ; i < shapes.isValid() i++);
                System.out.print(shapes);
                //System.out.println("%s") shapes;
                private static boolean isValid (shapes) ; {
                    return shapes.getArea() > 1000 && shapes.getColour().equals("green");


                }
    }


}
```

Comment: not sure why you need pattern-matching. Did you add tags on a whim?

Comment: Could you please add sample data of shapes.txt

Comment: You seem confused about the `parse(shape_data)` function.  This function should take one line of text at a time and return one shape.  You seem to have it generate a new Rectangle, and then a number of Circle shapes, and then return the first Rectangle object that was created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never enter your while loop, as endof is never false.

In your parse(shape_data), you need to decide which type of shape to create, based on parts[0].

Eg., for input "rectangle 68.01 77.63 orange"

```
public static Shape parse(String shape_data) {
    Shape shape;

    // TODO: complete this method
    String[] parts = shape_data.split(" ");
    switch(parts[0])
    {
        case "rectangle":
        shape = new Rectangle(parts[1], parts[2], parts[3]);
        break;
       etc...
    }
    return shape;
}
```

Note that this does no input validation, to see if the `shape_data` string actually contains enough arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Interface for the shape with color:

```
public interface ColoredShape {
    String getColor();
    double getArea();
}
```

Base colored shape class:

```
public abstract class BaseColoredShape implements ColoredShape {
    protected final String color;

    public BaseColoredShape(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
    @Override
    public String getColor() {
        return this.color;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.color;
    }
}
```

Rectangle implementation:

```
public class Rectangle extends BaseColoredShape {
    private final double width;
    private final double height;

    public Rectangle(String color, double width, double height) {
        super(color);
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    @Override
    public double getArea() {
        return width * height;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("rectangle %s %s %s", this.width, this.height, this.color);
    }
}
```

Cercle implementation:

```
public class Circle extends BaseColoredShape {
    private final double radius;

    public Circle(String colour, double radius) {
        super(colour);
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    @Override
    public double getArea() {
        return Math.PI * radius * radius;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("circle %s %s", this.radius, this.color);
    }
}
```

Input data parser(txt file) implemetation:

```
public class ShapeDataParser {
    private final String filepath;
    private final ColoredShapeFactory factory;

    public ShapeDataParser(String filepath) {
        this.filepath = filepath;
        this.factory = new ColoredShapeFactory();
    }

    public Stream<ColoredShape> parse() throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
        Path path = Paths.get(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(filepath).toURI());
        return Files.lines(path).map(this::stringToColoredShape);
    }

    private ColoredShape stringToColoredShape(String shapeStr) {
        String[] shapeParts = shapeStr.split(" ");
        String shapeType = shapeParts[0];
        if("circle".equals(shapeType)) {
            return factory.createCircle(shapeParts);
        }
        return factory.createRectangle(shapeParts);
    }
}
```

Shape factory:

```
public class ColoredShapeFactory {

    public ColoredShape createCircle(String[] shapeParts) {
        //TODO implement validation of shapeParts array
        double radius = Double.valueOf(shapeParts[1]);
        String color = shapeParts[2];
        return new Circle(color, radius);
    }

    public ColoredShape createRectangle(String[] shapeParts) {
        //TODO implement validation of shapeParts array
        double width = Double.valueOf(shapeParts[1]);
        double height = Double.valueOf(shapeParts[2]);
        String color = shapeParts[3];
        return new Rectangle(color, width, height);
    }
}
```

Finally entrypoint class:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

public class ShapeFilter {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
        ShapeDataParser parser = new ShapeDataParser("shape_data.txt");
        parser.parse()
                .filter(ShapeFilter::isValid)
                .forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    private static boolean isValid(ColoredShape shape) {
        return shape.getArea() > 1000 && shape.getColor().equals("green");
    }
}
```

Input data shape_data.txt:

```
rectangle 68.01 77.63 orange
circle 88.06 green
circle 18.29 green
circle 71.71 red
rectangle 17.91 8.75 orange
circle 2.16 white
rectangle 83.12 98.71 green
rectangle 37.27 35.93 green
rectangle 45.13 74.55 green
circle 36.62 white
circle 72.59 yellow
```

Output:

```
circle 88.06 green
circle 18.29 green
rectangle 83.12 98.71 green
rectangle 37.27 35.93 green
rectangle 45.13 74.55 green
```